# Start cmder with taskfile and 2 terminals open in split screen

Tags: cmder

I have an angular project and a java project and I would like to have a script for cmder that starts both of them in their specific directory in split window view so I can see both their logs.

Like this:
[image]

I know I can create a task file but I don't know how to configure it to create 2 (or more) terminals in split window view 
**EDIT:**
I would like to elaborate more on my question. I want with 1 script/command/configuration(?) to do the following thing:

1. Start cmder
2. on a terminal on top to run `ng serve` on the specific path that I have my angular application
3. create another terminal on the bottom and on a different path, I want to run `mvn spring-boot:run`
   so that I have a cmder environment that looks like in the image I posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may setup your configuration and specify to `cmder` save all tabs and reload
them at startup.

Right-click the green icon on the left of the title bar and choose `Settings...`.

In the Settings dialog, click on *Startup* and then on
*Auto save/restore opened tabs*, and finally on *Save settings*.
Your tab setup should now be saved on exit and restored on startup.

[image]

---

If you are trying to run several commands in two horizontal panes,
perhaps it would be simpler to put everything in a task file,
using the "Tasks file" option in the Startup section, like this :

```
-cur_console:d:"C:\Temp":t:Win1 command1
-cur_console:s1T50V:d:"C:\Temp\":t:Win2 command2
```

The first task starts in the opened console in folder `C:\Temp`,
is named `Win1` and runs `command1`.
The second task starts in the opened console in folder `C:\Temp`,
is named `Win2` and runs `command2`.
It is added to the first console - `s1T` - and takes 50 percent of the
height vertically (50V).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is partially what I want to do. I want to open the tabs and run a specific script on each tab/terminal. The save/restore only restores the tabs/terminals to their previous paths but does not run the script that was run last in them.

Comment: You may modify the scripts used for starting the tasks in Startup > Tasks.

Comment: Yes ok, so how do I do, what I asked?

Comment: You will see the two tasks you started in the startup task (first one normally) and you can modify the commands. You will need to read the help, though.

Comment: thank you. I did that and could not figure it out that's why I asked for help. I select the "save settings", then I create 2 commands like the ones that I want, then what? How do I create a script that starts cmder and runs these 2 commands in a split window of terminals?

Comment: I added a simpler option, which may be more in line with what you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Even though @harrymc answered the question I want to add the exact solution to my question here:

- Create a file with the following 2 lines (for an explanation for each command look at @harrymc's post above)

  `-cur_console:d:"C:\Temp\frontend\":t:frontEnd "ng serve"`
  `-cur_console:s1T50V:d:"C:\Temp\server\":t:server "mvn spring-boot:run"`
- Open cmder -> Settings -> Startup -> Tasks File -> (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and select the saved file from the previous step.
- Save and restart

[image]